# Move (download and delete) files from SFTP server

Tags: sftp, winscp

I am using a WinSCP (SFTP) script to move files off a SFTP server. Something like this:

```
get *.ecx
```

But this only "copies" files from remote to local. I need to move files off the server. What server command can I use to move multiple files? `mv` doesn't seem to work as it looks like both arguments are remote.

I was not able to determine SFTP server being used:

> winscp> version
>   Unknown command 'version'.

Comment: Why not just "Delete" the files after you "Get" them?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 But I'm doing multiple files at once and that isn't connected w/ a verify. What if 1 fails, and 9 succeed on a get? If I `delete *.ecx` I'll be losing a file.

Comment: There is no generic FTP Move command, it's just get+delete.  Your specific FTP server MAY have a custom MOVE command (never sene one that does though), but since you can't figure out which FTP server you're connecting to, it's impossible to say. :)  Try "Help" at the FTP command prompt and see if a Server->Client Move command is shown. If not, then you're probably stuck with Get+Delete.

Comment: you can always boot from a linux live CD, and open a file manager window to `sshfs://servername/path/to/files`, so you can make use of Gnomes file management capabilities. perhaps even use rsync to grab the files, so you can be sure they are verified, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get

```
-delete      Delete source remote file(s) after transfer.
```